Accessing any selected instance of Bentley MicroStation V8i from external application in C#
I have a C# application which accessess Microstation (V8i) via it's API. The problem is, if there are several instances of MicroStation open simultaneously, only the instance which was opened first is accessed.
I found an article dealing with such a problem (the example there is AutoCAD) Accessing COM applications from the Running Object Table however it did not work in this case. The returned list of IMoniker objects found when filtering the Running Object Table by "MicroStationDGN.ApplicationObjectConnector" contained as many objects as Microstation instances opened, however they all seemed to be the same object (like a singleton).
A code snippet describing the test is below. The whole method GetRunningInstances(progId) is in the link, I did not want to duplicate it here.
            string progId = "MicroStationDGN.ApplicationObjectConnector";

            List<object> instances = GetRunningInstances(progId);
            bool theSame = instances[0] == instances[1];    //at least 2 instances, returns true

Is there a way to access a selected instance of open Microstation instances?
Marek Praski

I asked the same question at a dedicated Microstation programming forum and the answer was, in short, this could not be done.
